# Url aliases for individual resources in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, I have a model Page which represents one HTML "article" about some aspect of my organisation.

Now, I would like to give some of these pages their own top-level URL like "/products" and "/contact-us". However, I would prefer to do this in a dynamic (database-driven) way i.e. not have to add a `match` clause for each. The reason is I need to link to some pages in the main menu, but obviously don't know which id number they will get in each deployment.

What would be the best-practice way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the end of routes.rb add

```
get "/:page" => "main#page"
```

in page action use params[:page] to find page in db and render it using

```
render :inline => @model.haml, :type => 'haml', :layout => true
```

if u r using haml ofc